# Nostyle is changed for Angular Material Dynamic Table

Tags: angular

I used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-dynamic-table) angular material dynamic table. I want to change columns width but I could not change any style in that table. [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-table-qdaugf) is [demo page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-table) for testing. I added below CSS for testing whether anything changes:

```
table, table td, table tr td, table th, .mat-cell, mdt-dynamic-table, mdt-dynamic-table table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Why any styles are not working for that table? How can I resize column width or change any style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your table is not part of the component where you want to style it.

Did you try with `::ng-deep`?

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

```
:host ::ng-deep table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What doe is it mean the table is not part of the component. It is a angular package and I think that it uses angular material default table in background. Why di this problem happen?

Comment: Glad that it helped. Angular encapsulates all Components. Your angular material table is also a component (child). If you put your table in another component (parent) and you put styles for the child in it, the child component doesn't know anything from it.

You can solve that with `::ng-deep` or if you set `viewEncapsulation` to none.
You can have a look here for further information: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation